# Magento, template path hints issue

Tags: magento, frontend, magento-1.9

I have activated "Template Path Hints" and "Add Block Names to Hints", from the developer options.

The hints are showing on the front-end, however I'm not able to scroll down below a certain point.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If without path hints everything is working correctly then the problem is in your theme. Try to use the browser inspector ;-)

Comment: Yup its working absolutely fine otherwise. Will have a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use free Magento extension for better help. It will work for frontend as well as the admin section too. Check it here at this URL.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This extensions just adds the possibility to enable the path hints via URL, but the functionality itself comes from the Magento core (it will work in the same way as it would if it were enabled via admin).